# Does the CRTP "pitfall workaround" negate the early binding benefits?

Tags: c++, crtp, static-polymorphism, early-binding

In order to store CRTP object pointers in a homogenous container the templated base class can itself be derived from a class `common_base` that defines a pure virtual interface and (if required) a virtual destructor. This is sometimes referred to as the CRTP pitfall workaround.

```
class common_base
{
public:
  virtual ~common_base() {}
};

template<typename T> class base : public common_base {

public:
  void func() {
    printf("base func()\n");
    static_cast<T*>(this)->func();
  }

};

class derived : public base<derived> {

public:
    void func() {
        printf("derived func()\n");
    }
};
```

```
derived d;
base<derived>& b = d;

d.func();   // Output: derived func()

b.func();   // Output: base func()
            //         derived func()
```

All good. Now let's say I want to use the workaround to not only store `derived` objects in a container, but to also call a common interface on those objects. So I change `common_base` to be:

```
class common_base
{
public:
  virtual ~common_base() {}
  virtual void func() = 0;
};
```

```
derived d;
base<derived>& b = d;
common_base& c = d;

d.func();   // Output: derived func()

b.func();   // Output: derived func()

c.func();   // Output: derived func()
```

The above pure virtual function pattern is present in references I've seen but it looks like it causes a vtable to be used in resolving the `func()` calls at runtime, which negates the performance benefit of the compile time polymorphism of CRTP. Is it not possible to declare a common base interface with CRTP early binding in this way?

References:

[Modern C++ Programming Cookbook - Second Edition](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/programming/9781800208988/10/ch10lvl1sec19/static-polymorphism-with-the-curiously-recurring-template-pattern)

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern#Pitfalls)

Comment: The bottom-line question you should ask if `c.func()` can have enough information to resolve the dispatch at compile time. The answer is no because `common_base` knows nothing about the derived `T`. There is not enough type information to resolve the call to `T::func` because `common_base` erased it.

Comment: Would `d.func();` use run-time vtable dispatch or not, depends  on implementation and optimization mode.

Comment: *"CRTP pitfall workaround"* explained in the first paragraph is not a thing. Adding abstract base interface won't make it possible to store CRTP objects in a homogenous container. *"but to also call a common interface on those objects"* - CRTP performs compile-time calls of "virtual" methods from inside of CRTP class and related templates so in order to use it you'll need to provide an instance of derived class. If you use an abstract base class with actual virtual methods then you essentially hit the runtime dispatch switch.

Comment: @user7860670 You probably had mean "contigous container". Homegenous container includes one, which would store just pointers to same type.. Technically the former is possible, but that requres storing some meta-type information within base class (its size, type, etc.)

Comment: can you provide a reference for "CRTP pitfall workaround" ? I tried to research it, but the only thing I found was this question

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Storing *pointers* to CRTP objects in a homogenous container is not the same as storing CRTP objects in a homogenous container though.

Comment: @user7860670 homogenum  supposes "same type". In C++ *nothing* allows to store different types in a homogenous container without type erasure.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie That's what i'm talking about.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai edited to add the references where this is described.

Comment: @user7860670 you're right the workaround is just storing pointers to the abstract base class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CRTP (or anything else for that matter) is *not* a way to have benefits of late binding without actually having late bindings. If late bindings were replaceable by a better mechanism, they would have been replaced. They have not, and they are not.

CRTP is a way of having *common code base* (living in a template) without having a *common base class* (because templates are not classes). Absence of a common base class is *the whole point*. Since there is no common base class, the dynamic type is either the same as the static type or is embedded in the static type as a template parameter, so it's always statically known, and no dynamic dispatch is needed. You cannot reintroduce a common base class into the picture and still use static dispatch everywhere. That would require a miracle, and miracles are forbidden in C++.

So does this "CRTP pitfall workaround" actually achieve anything? Let's have a closer look. The book referenced in the question shows an example:

```
class controlbase
{
public:
  virtual void draw() = 0;
  virtual ~controlbase() {}
};
template <class T>
class control : public controlbase
{
public:
  virtual void draw() override
  {
    static_cast<T*>(this)->erase_background();
    static_cast<T*>(this)->paint();
  }
};
```

Derived classes like `class button : public control<button>` implement `erase_background` and `paint`.

In this setting, `draw` is called with the dynamic dispatch mechanism, while `erase_background` and `paint` are dispatched statically. (There is no contradiction with the above: only `draw` belongs to the common base class, and calls to `draw` need to be dynamically dispatched; other calls are not made to methods of the common base class, and those can be in principle statically dispatched). So there's a net win: all calls but one are effectively devirtualised. On the other hand, a competent optimiser should *in principle* be able to always devirtualise those other calls without the programmer having to resort to CRTP, although I don't know of a compiler that is able to do it.

Comment: So in terms of indirection the workaround is only beneficial if the number of static dispatches done by the virtual (`draw()`) is *more than two*, since the virtual itself incurs 2 indirections (vtable lookup + pointer). Otherwise we may as well just use virtual dispatch. In the example there are 4 indirections total (2 for virtual call + 2 calls via pointer), which is the same as if `erase_background()` and `paint()` were both dispatched virtually (2 + 2). Although the cache performance of each approach may be different due to memory layout.

Comment: @sleep Not sure how your arithmetic works, you either have (in a straightforward implementation) 2 virtual calls + 1 non-virtual (assuming `draw` is non-virtual), or (in a CRTP implementation) 1 virtual + 2 non-virtual.

Comment: I’m counting indirections. A virtual call costs 2.

Comment: So in your calculations a non-virtual call to `erase_background` and a non-virtual call to `paint` cost 1 each, while a non-virtual call to `draw` costs 0. How are the two mechanisms different? Have you looked at the actual assembly? (If `draw` can be inlined, so can be the other non-virtual calls).

Comment: In the non-CRTP case draw() does not exist.

Comment: "draw() does not exist" @sleep Not sure why you would say that, but whatever floats your boat.